# hfuzz not working in table environment

Tags: warnings, logging, overfull

dear internet stranger. I just wanted to turn off some overfull hbox warnings when I ran into a problem. I could not turn off warnings inside a table environment. What can I do to fix this?

Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\hfuzz=1000pt
\begin{document}

\[qwertzuiopasdfghjkqwertfghjkvfghjklzuioasdfghjkwertzuiertzuioxcvbnmdfghzujikghj\]

\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{cccc}
asd&asd&asd&asdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdads
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

The warning in the formula is supressed but the one in the table is not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

tables, parboxes etc reset various settings (via `\@parboxrestore`) so you need to set it locally, or modify that command.

```
\documentclass{article}
\hfuzz=1000pt
\begin{document}

\[qwertzuiopasdfghjkqwertfghjkvfghjklzuioasdfghjkwertzuiertzuioxcvbnmdfghzujikghj\]

\begin{table}\hfuzz=1000pt
\begin{tabular}{cccc}
asd&asd&asd&asdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdads
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```